# CloudFormation ImportValue in JSON Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What is the proper way to import a Stack Export in a JSON policy blob, using YAML as the Resource definition?:

I have the following Output/Export:

```
Outputs:
  oParameterStoreAccessRoleArn:
    Description: "ARN of the newly-created role above"
    Value: !GetAtt rParameterStoreAccessRole.Arn
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-oParameterStoreAccessRoleArn
```

and I am trying to create a Secrets Manager Secret Resource Policy with the [AWS::SecretsManager::ResourcePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-resourcepolicy.html):

I would like to replace the `IMPORTVALUEHERE` (the ARN) with the Value of the Export above.

```
  rSecretPolicyKubernetesVpcId:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::ResourcePolicy
    Properties:
      ResourcePolicy:

        {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {"AWS": "IMPORTVALUEHERE:"}
            }
          ]
        
        }
      SecretId: !Ref rSecretKubernetesVpcId
```

**What is the correct way to use Fn::ImportValue to insert the Export ARN into the JSON Resource Policy Block?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily write the policy as yaml, which would make it more readable, in my opinion.

You can also use a [`!Sub`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) function in which you provide the value as a second parameter to the function.

An example from the docs:

```yaml
!Sub
  - String
  - Var1Name: Var1Value
    Var2Name: Var2Value
```

Which in your case should become:

```yaml
rSecretPolicyKubernetesVpcId:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::ResourcePolicy
    Properties:
      ResourcePolicy: !Sub
        - {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {"AWS": "IMPORTVALUEHERE"}
              }
            ]
          }
        - IMPORTVALUEHERE: !ImportValue StackName-oParameterStoreAccessRoleArn
      SecretId: !Ref rSecretKubernetesVpcId
```

(Edit)

An example of a policy entirely in yaml. I've put in an `ImportValue` statement as an extra.

```yaml
  CodeBuildServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codebuild.amazonaws.com
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub '${Environment}-pipeline-codebuild'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - s3:ListBucket
                  - s3:GetObjectVersion
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:PutObject
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: 
                  - !ImportValue some-value-to-import
```

Comment: Thank you! The documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-resourcepolicy.html states that the policy expects a JSON block. I would love to write this in YAML. Do you have any thoughts on the support of that here?

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON and can be used almost interchangeable in the cloudformation. I'll edit my answer to add an example of a policy in yaml.

Comment: (Any JSON is valid YAML too, for the record.)

Comment: @Patrick remember your SO ettique and upvote this answer in addition to accepting it :)